# two column vectors in beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex

How to input the code in beamer to get the two column vectors as in the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
1\\ 0\\ -1
\end{pmatrix*},\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
1\\ 0\\ -1
\end{pmatrix*}
\end{Bmatrix}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Above solution works at any document class. For example, at `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Two column vectors presented by Beamer}
\[
A=\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
1\\ 0\\ -1
\end{pmatrix*},\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
1\\ 0\\ -1
\end{pmatrix*}
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This work in any document class. Just replace `article` with `beamer`. However, you not provide any your attempt of writing your code ...

Comment: Thanks! I have another question. How to input the code to get the form of $A=some matrix$?

Comment: @mathbeginner, as you write in comment. instead of "some matrix" write code of matrix. To make yourself more familiar with writing math in LaTeX, please read some introductory text about this, for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics.